# dynamic loading with prettyphoto jquery html php

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

hello there I wish to create a dynamic content gallery with prettyphoto until now the code works except for a few things.my link html is as follow:

`<a href="<?php echo $pic;?>" rel="prettyPhoto['<?php echo $gal;?>']"></a>`

as you can see I load the href attribute with php.next to this link there 's an input type hidden that holds the path on the server of the gallery.on click on the link the path and the gallery name is posted through ajax the result being more links like this one each pointing on an image in the gallery and all sharing the same gallery name.here's the jquery

```
     $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
  slideshow: 5000,
autoplay_slideshow: false
});
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").on('click',function(){
var nxt=$(this).next().val();//get gallerypath
var galname="";
var totalgal="<?php echo $cpu;?>";//get total of galleries
var who=$(this);
for(i=1;i<totalgal;i++)
{

if($(this).next().hasClass('gallery'+i))
{
  galname="gallery"+i;


$.post("getgallery.php",{path:nxt,name:galname},function(d){
if(d)
{

  who.after(d);

}
});
  }
  else
    continue;
}
});
```

the results append all links to the initial one so that we now have:

```
<a href="image link" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"></a>
<a href="image link" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"></a>
<a href="image link" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"></a>
<a href="image link" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"></a>
```

but when the pretty photo shows up it only displays the topmost link picture i cant browse the other pictures i cant figure out why

Comment: I dont know if i understood correctly but i guess youre adding some images with ajax then you see they are added in output but they dont exist in gallery? If that's the problem you may need to call `$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto()` again after adding new items.

Comment: thank you for the tip but i ve already done that didnt work for me.when i click on the prettyphoto link it retrieves all the images from the gallery folder and then append them to the initial link as well as giving them the same rel attribute and gallery and then prettyphoto 's box is displayed.unfortunately it only display the first picture and doesnt show the rest not even the controls for next and previous

Comment: Check [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/9KmVc/) please. If you click `ADD NEW` the new image is gonna be added but it's not gonna be actually in the gallery. If you click `ADD NEW AND CALL FN` the image is gonna be also added into galery because in the `.click` fn for this button we're also calling `.prettyPhoto()` again. BTW i just saw you dont have `<img>`s inside `<a>`s in your `html output` example. I assume it's not actually happening this way or is it? o.O

Comment: yes indeed there's no img inside the a tags though i put some in the first place but it provided me only with the thumbnails which i do not need for this particular case....i cant run your fiddle i mean when clicking on the buttons nothing happens

Comment: It only runs in firefox i guess since i only copy/pasted the sources from their site. If you have a chance to run this on ff please do

Comment: still no luck on firefox too i dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: i noticed on some site that use this technique that there's a hashtag in the url like this`#prettyPhoto[gallery1]/2/` to let people go to the next or previous is it relevant?

Comment: i finally was able to find out what i was doing wrong it was only the prettyphoto.js version thank you buddy for the help